# Codeigniter: __construct variable into my another function

Tags: php, codeigniter

I need to print first segment variable in my function from __construct, but I get error:

Code:

```
<?php if (!defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');

class Main extends CI_Controller {

    public $data = array();

    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
        $data['seg'] = $this->uri->segment(1);
        $data['seg'] == 'en' ? $data['seg'] = 'en' : $data['seg'] = 'ge';
    }

    public function index()
    {
        echo "test";
    }

    public function Test()
    {
        echo $data['seg'] . " - TEST";
    }

}

/* End of file  */
/* Location: ./application/controllers/Main.php */
```

Error:

```
A PHP Error was encountered
Severity: Notice
Message: Undefined variable: data

Filename: controllers/Main.php
Line Number: 21
Backtrace:
File: D:\www\test\application\controllers\Main.php
Line: 21
Function: _error_handler
File: D:\www\test\index.php
Line: 315
Function: require_once

- TEST
```

I'm trying to search it in Google and Stackoverflow But I cant fix this problem. Thanks all.

Comment: use `$this->data['seg']=$this->uri->segment(1);` and so on every where

Comment: @GiorgiBulia if you find any answers that help don't forget to accept them

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to use `$this` to set or get value of `$data` which is in `class` scope. I have fixed your code here, give a try.

```
<?php if (!defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');

class Main extends CI_Controller
{
    public $data = array();

    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();

        $this->data['seg'] = $this->uri->segment(1);
        $this->data['seg'] == 'en' ? $this->data['seg'] = 'en' : $this->data['seg'] = 'ge';
    }

    public function index()
    {
        echo "test";
    }

    public function Test()
    {
        echo $this->data['seg'] . " - TEST";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

As Manual http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.visibility.php

You can access public variable by

```
$this->data['seg']=..........;
```

Answer (score 0):

### Codeigniter

```
class Main extends CI_Controller {

    public $data = array();    

    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->data['seg'] = $this->uri->segment(1);
        $this->data['seg'] == 'en' ? $this->data['seg'] = 'en' : $this->data['seg'] = 'ge';
    }

    public function index()
    {
        echo "test";
    }

    public function Test()
    {
        echo $this->data['seg'] . " - TEST";
    }

}
```

Comment: approve the edits, because you have to put $this in other parts where i have put

Comment: welocme@GiorgiBulia.. :)